# Concurrent safe short unique integer id generation in nodeJS

Tags: node.js, multithreading, cluster-computing, computer-science, rethinkdb

I have a node application where I am using rethinkdb as database. The id rethinkdb generates for each document is not human readable and not suitable for real world reference purpose.

For example, each user I create I want to have a short integer id which I can use to refer that user in real world. The id I get from database is not suitable for that.

What would be a concurrent safe way to generate a short unique integer id ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building off of @Suvitruf 's answer you can accomplish this in pure reql using the following where "last" is a table that contains the last id. Modifications made here are specifically for parallel updates. Instead of individual id updates for each update, the number block is reserved in 1 insert that is part of the query. Please award any points to his answer.

```
r([{ foo: 'a' }, { foo: 'b'}])
.do(records => {
    return r.table('lastId').get('last')('current')
  .do(current => {
    return r.table('lastId').get('last').update({ current: current.add(records.count()) })
    .do(() => {
      return r.range(0, records.count()).map(idx => {
        return records.nth(idx).merge(rec => {
            return { id: current.add(idx) }
        })
      })
    })
  })
})
.coerceTo('array')
.do(records => {
    return r.table('ids').insert(records)    
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create new table, for example, System.

Add to this table just one record:

```
{
    id: "myLastId",
    current: 0
}
```

When you want to insert new record to another table, you need to increment this id first and return it:

```
const getNewId = r.table("System").get("myLastId").update({
                                current: r.row("current").add(1)
                            },
                            {returnChanges: true});
```

Your new id will be in `result.changes[0]["new_val"].current`. Now, you can insert new record with this id.

Yes, you have to send additional request each time you want to insert new record, but, at least, this method is 100% atomic and synchronized between all nodes in cluster.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I think this will not work in the case when update is done parallely.

Comment: how does this work when doing say r.table('mytable').insert([ record1, record2, ....])

Comment: @vbranden if you have X records to insert you can `add` X to `current`. In `result.changes[0]["new_val"].current` will be the last id. So, if the `current` was `3`, you added, for example, `3`. Not it has value `6`. So, you have ids: `4`, `5`, `6`. You can setup them for you records to insert.

Comment: i have implemented your approach in pure reql. I could not post it here so i made a new anwer. if you approve i can add it to your answer so you get the credit.

Comment: @vbranden nice. No need to add it to my answer, your effort should be awarded ^_^